# Return numbers in text after specific string

Tags: python, regex

I have to examine several text files and have to return the 10 digit number after the word "INDEX KEY" from those text files. (The numbers always contain 10 digits)

An example of a part of the text is here:

"THIS IS THE TEXT BEFORE CENTRAL INDEX KEY: 0000341527 THIS IS THE TEXT AFTER"

-> I want that my code returns: 00003415227

The text is saved as the variable "doc" and contains a lot of text in which "INDEX KEY" might appear more than one time. I want to grab only the number following the first occurence of "INDEX KEY".

I know its working with a regular expression and I use them in other parts of my code without problems but somehow I do not get it. Answers mentioned on previous discussions here did also not work out.

If anyone knows how I can do that, I would be really glad!

Answer (score 3):

Use `re.search` with pattern `r"INDEX KEY: (\d*)"`

**Ex:**

```
import re

s = "THIS IS THE TEXT BEFORE CENTRAL INDEX KEY: 0000341527 THIS IS THE TEXT AFTER. THIS IS THE TEXT BEFORE CENTRAL INDEX KEY: 0000341527 THIS IS THE TEXT AFTER"
m = re.search(r"INDEX KEY: (\d*)", s)
if m:
    print(m.group(1))
```

**Output:**

```
0000341527
```

Comment: Thanks! That works for a string that I wrote. However, if I want to refer to my file, e.g. abc.txt = x, then m = re.search(r"INDEX KEY: (\d*)", x) does not work.